# how to get cognito user id when login with email and password login in android

Tags: android, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am doing user registration with email and password using Amazon Cognito services in Android. I am successful in registration, login and forgot password flows.

I am getting the cognito user id with the below code, **the problem is i am getting the same cognito user id that i received during first time login for the other users too. i.e., when i login next time with different credentials i'm getting the same cognito user id of the first user**:

```
       credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(), // Context
                "us-east-1:2ce7b2c2-898f-4a26-9066-d4feff8ebfe4", //Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );

        Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super String> subscriber) {
                identityId = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();                    
            }
        })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
    }
```

Please bear with my questions as I am starter so help and share ideas on how these cognito user ids work

1. as I believe the Cognito user id remains unique for each user
2. Cognito user id does not change when login in different devices like ios/web too.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are getting the cached identity id and credentials on the device. Can you please try calling credentialsProvider.clear() when a new user logs in or you sign out the user. This should clear the cached identity id.

Comment: may be you are right, but one thing is i'm not getting the same Cognito User Id when same user login in my Android app and iOS app. I just tried to test if the IDs are identical for the user across different platform - Android / iOS.                                                                                   Even the ids for the same user is different (not matching with the same ID i received during the first time login) when i clear the cache in android app.